# How to identify the shannavathi (96) days of an year for tharpanam?

Tags: rituals, name, identification-request

Shannavathi Tharpanam - means 96 days of oblations to our elders. While [this](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090227083847AAYI1a3) answer beautifully explains how the count 96 is arrived, I am still perplexed on how to identify them on the calendar/panchangam(almanac)?

To avoid a dead link, I quote the answer that I referred here:

> 1) Number of Shraddham or Tharpana per year:
>
> Shannavathi - 96 days when Shraddham or atleast Tharpana is to be
>   performed.
>
> The following are the 96 days:
>
> Amavasya - 12
>
> Masapirappu (Sankramanas) - 12
>
> Pournami - 12
>
> Kruthayugathi - 1
>
> Threthayugathi - 1
>
> Dwaparayugathi - 1
>
> Kaliyugathi - 1
>
> Vaithruthi Yogas - 14
>
> Vyatheepatha Yoga -14
>
> Mahalayathi -16
>
> Ashtaka - 4
>
> Anvashtaka - 4
>
> Thisroshtaka -4
>
> Apart from the listed days above, one has to perform the Tharppanam on
>   the Eclipse days and also on the next day to Mathru/Pithru Srardha
>   days.
>
> According to the Vaidhyanatheeyam and Srivaishnava Deepika, a dutiful
>   Brahmin has to perform 96 tharppanams in a year, as stipulated in the
>   Vedic scripts. Listed above are the days on which a Brahmin has to
>   perform his duty in Thila tharpana roopam. Out of these, the Mahalaya
>   Tharpanam can be done with Hiranyam or with Brahmmana bhojanam also;
>   if not on all the sixteen days, any one day that one considers himself
>   as most important – viz. Mahabharani, Madhyashtami or on his mathru/
>   pithru srardha thithi days that falls during Mahalayam.
>
> If one cannot afford to perform the Tharsha Srardham known as Thila
>   tharppanam on all the above days, one should stick to minimum possible
>   on Amavasya, Mesha Sangramanam, Dakshinayana punyakaalam, Thula Vishu
>   Punyakalam, Utharayana punyakalam, Mahalaya Tharpanam (one day),
>   Visible Surya/Chandra Grahana days and also on the next days to
>   Mathru/Pithru srardha.
>
> 2) Shraddham and Tharpana in life time:
>
> (i) Pinda Tharpanam at Badrinath:
>
> The Pinda Tharpanam at Brahma Kapalam, Badrinath is to be done atleast
>   once in life time by all.
>
> (ii) Shraddham and Tharpanam at Gaya:
>
> The following are to be performed atleast once in life time by all at
>   Gaya.
>
> a) Pinda and Thila Tharpanam at the riverbed Falgu
>
> b) Pinda Tharpanam at Vishnupadam
>
> c) Shraddham at Gaya
>
> d) Pinda Tharpanam at Akshayavada Source(s):
>   http://www.trsiyengar.com/id139.shtml C. Sri Vidya Rajagopalan · 8
>   years ago

Of these listed days, it is easy for me to find:

> Amavasya - 12 
>   Masapirappu (Sankramanas) - 12 
>   Pournami - 12 
>   Mahalayathi -16

While I have no clue on how to find:

> Kruthayugathi - 1 
>   Threthayugathi - 1 
>   Dwaparayugathi - 1 
>   Kaliyugathi - 1 
>   Vaithruthi Yogas - 14 
>   Vyatheepatha Yoga -14 
>   Ashtaka - 4 
>   Anvashtaka - 4 
>   Thisroshtaka -4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My reference here is the book ["Essence of Dharma Sindhu" @Kamakoti.org](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php)

The 96(Shannavati) Shraddha days are:

> In fact in each year there are ninety six Shraaddhas to be performed
>   and these are: **twelve Amavasyas, four yugaadis, fourteen
>   Manvantaraas, Twelve Kranthis, Twelve Vaidhritis, twelve
>   Vyatipaataas, Mahalayaas fifteen , Ashtakas as five,
>   Anvashtakas five , Purveddha shraaddhas five, totalling ‘Shannavati’
>   Shraaddhaas.**

Now you have said that you already know some of these days. Those which are missing from your list and those days which you can't identify are given below:

**4 Yugadi days(Yugadi day is the day on which the Yuga is believed to have started):**

**Kritha Yugadi-Aksahya Navami**(Month-Karthik,Paksha-Sukla,Tithi-Navami)

**Treta Yugadi-Akshaya Tritiya**(Vaishakh,Sukla,Triteeya)

**Dwapara Yugadi-Magha Bahula Trayodashi**(Magha,Krishna,Trayodashi)

**Kali Yugadi-Bhadrapada Krishna Trayodashi**.

> Kali Yuga started on Bhadrapada, Krishnapaksha -13th day, in
>   Vyatipaat yoga at midnight, in the Aashlesha Nakshatra and the age of
>   the Kali Yuga has been fixed as 5101 years as till date that is Vikram
>   Samvat 2057 = Shaka 1922 = 2000 AD.

**12 Vyaptipata and 12 Vaidhruti Yogas:**

In a year the Vyaptipata Yogas and Vaidruthi Yoga days are each 12 in number and not 14 like you mentioned.(See my quote above,they list 12 days for each of these yogas).

A hindu day consist of 5 limbs or the "Panchangas" one of which is the Yoga other 4 being Tithi,Nakshtra,Vara and Karana.

You can check on any Panchanga site(like [Drikpanchang.com](http://www.drikpanchang.com/?l=10436) ) for Vyaptipata and Vaidruthi Yoga days for your place.This will give you the 24 Shraddha days in a year.

**Five Purvavedu days:**

> Five Purvavedu or **Saptami days of Krishna Pakshas of Bhadrapada, Marg
>   ashira, Pushya, Maagha, and Phalgunaas**;

**14 Manvadis(the day on which each Manvantara started):**

> On the Chaitra Shukla Triteeya itself the Manvaadis or the beginning
>   of reign of Fourteen Manus ; **in fact the Manvaadis are celebrated on
>   Chaitra Shukla Triteeya and Purnima, Jyeshtha Purnima, Ashadha Shukla
>   Dashami and Purnima, Shravana Krishna ashtami, Bhadrapada Shukla
>   Triteeya, Ashvayuja Shukla Navami, Kartika Shukla Dwadashi and
>   Pournamaasi, Pousha Shuklaikaadashi, Maagha Shukla Saptami and
>   Phalguna Purnima and Amavaashya**

**5 Ashtakas and 5 Anashtakas days** :

> Ashtami Tithis of Krishna Pakshas of the afore-mentioned Maasaas(the
>   5 months mentioned under Purbavedu days) are the 5 Ashtakas and the
>   and Anvashtaka Krishna Navamis of the same 5 Months.